# How to use a filter view with protected cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When having a Google Sheets file with a lot of users with edit rights I advice the users to use individual filter views per user (not filters) to filter the data.

As soon as one cell in the file is protected for the users they can no longer create a filter view for all columns but only a filter view on the columns without protected cells.

Why is it not possible to use filter views on protected cells or columns? The users don't want to edit the cells, they just want to filter.

Possible options I have tested:

- If the users select a protected cell they are able to create a *temporary* filter view and filter all columns. Great! But of course they can not save this filter view for later use
- If a person with edit rights on the protected cells creates a filter view and let other users use it the other users can't filter data, too. Same situation when they duplicate an existing
  filter view
- When I delete the protection of certain cells and protect the whole sheet everybody is able to use filter views on all rows. But of course they can't edit the rows where they have to put data in anymore

Is there are Apps Script code I could use?